# Distribution of positions for simple random walk

Tags: probability-distributions, random-walk

Suppose we have a symmetric simple random walk and the step is 1 and -1. Obviously, if we take N steps, the PMF of position k for N steps is given by
$${{N}\choose{\frac{k+N}{2}}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^N$$
And if N is large, this follows the normal distribution with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{N}$.
But how can I obtain the distribution of position for a certain random walk.

For example, we ran a 10000 steps random walk simulation, and the hist is as follows for each position.
[image: Hist of simulated random walk]

But it was not a normal distribution, and it was thinner than normal distribution.

Is there a way to use a distribution function to generate the approximate hist without doing random walk simulation？ In this way, it is more efficient. And we could obtain the approximate maximum and minimum without doing simulation.

I checked many papers, but no answer exists.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you only have one sequence, then it is deterministic, no?

Comment: Yeah, but I have a bunch of random walks. And I want to know the distribution of each point based on this huge amount of random walks. Obviously, I could do simulation mutiple times to get these results, but I want to know is there a way to represent this distribution with math instead of  doing simulation.